# Python - How to read multiple files, process and write to multiple files

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a Source code Plagiarism detection tool in Python. I am trying to take input from multiple python program files present in an input directory, carry out some processing stuff and write the output to multiple files.

Here's what I'm trying to do in my code:

I have 2 files:

1. **main.py**, where I'm opening multiple files and calling my class & methods
2. **pyscp.py** from package **SoftPlag**, where the code is written for the processing of the input files.

### **main.py**

```
from SoftPlag import *
import os

inputdir = "/path/to/input/directory"
outputdir = "/path/to/output/directory"
filelist = os.listdir(inputdir)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    for i in filelist:
        with open(inputdir + i, 'r') as f:
            fin = f.read()
            if i.endswith(".py"):
                scp=Pyscp()    
                scp.pscpp(fin)
                f.flush()       
            f.close()
```

### **pyscp.py**

> This is the file where the processing stuff is. After each file is
>   processed, the corresponding output is to be written to a file in its
>   output directory

```
import re
import keyword
import os

inputdir = "/path/to/input/directory"
outputdir = "/path/to/output/directory"
filelist = os.listdir(inputdir)
frequency={}
class Pyscp():
#Python source-code processing class
    def pscpp(self,fin):
        #remove special characters from string and convert to lower-case 
        char_string=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z._]', ' ', fin).lower()

        #remove single occurrences of characters 
        final_string=re.sub(r'(?:^| )\w(?:$| )', '', char_string).strip() 

        reservedWords={} #empty list to store the reserved keywords
        reservedWords=keyword.kwlist #reserved keywords assigned to reservedWords list

        for word in reservedWords:
            #checking if reserved keyword exists in string or not 
            if word in final_string:
                #substitute reserved keywords with no spaces
                final_string=re.sub(r'\b' + word +r'\b', '', final_string)

            else:
                continue

        for i in filelist:
            file_output = open(os.path.join(outputdir + i +".out"), 'w')
            file_output.write(final_string)
            file_output.close()
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I'm able to open multiple files using os package using a single file object and do the processing stuff on them, but it is not writing to multiple files properly .i.e. it is writing the output data of the first file multiple times and not writing different output data.

**Please help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over your files again in `pyscp.py`. You are effectively creating a nested loop, which looks kind of like this:

```
for i_main in filelist:
    # here you are reading your inputfile
    # then you do some processing
    for i_pyscp in filelist:
        # here you are writing to outputfile
```

This of course writes all your results for all input files to all output files. And since you are opening them with the `'w'` attribute, they are overwritten, leaving only the output of the final iteration of the outer loop, i.e. the last file in `filelist`.

I would suggest to remove the loop in `pyscp.py` and just do `return final_string`. In `main.py` you can then write it to a file.

Three more comments about `main.py`:

1. I am surprised you don't get a "File not found" error in `open(inputdir + i, 'r')` since you are missing a path separator. `open(os.path.join(inputdir + i), 'r')` would be the way to go here.
2. Usually you don't need `f.flush()`, as `f.close()` will take care of it for you. Also you are not writing any data to your input file.
3. Also, you don't need `f.close()` since the `with` statement takes care of it your for.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should write the code block of function 'pscpp(self,fin)' inside 'main.py', as suggested by @ArunKumar above? Regarding the 3 points which you mentioned:
1. I have implemented as you suggested.
2 & 3. I had to use f.flush() as I'm observing that memory cleanup is not happening properly. If I'm trying to take input from file1.py & file2.py, it is also taking input from file1.java from memory & I get file1.py, file1.py~,file2.py,file2.py~ & file1.java~. Any effective way for memory cleanup?

Comment: The most important thing is to not use a loop when writing your output files.
You can leave the processing part in the `pyscp.py` if it suits your needs. You may also leave writing your output files there, but then you need to pass the filename in your function call. My recommandation is to move writing the files to where you read them. So your `pyscp.py` would be all about the processing, and you do not need to worry about filenames and paths there. That would be restricted to your `main.py`

Comment: About the extra files: I do not see why Python would access those, so I do not know where your memory issue is coming from. The filenames ending in `~` look like temporary files as some editors create them to store (and recover) unsaved changes. But based on your code I would expect Python ignores them.

Comment: I have now placed the reading and writing of files together inside my main.py. So, with this changes, file reading and writing is working properly. My requirement now is that I require the variable 'final_string' which is present inside pyscp.py file. This variable stores the processing output for each file and is required to be written to its corresponding file. Can 'final_string' variable be imported into 'main.py' or is there any other solution?

Comment: Are you asking how to return a value from a function? Simply add to the end of your `pscpp()` function definition `return final_string`. In `main.py` you then call it with `final_string = scp.pscpp(fin)`.

Comment: As @ArunKumar mentioned, I have changed 'scp.pscpp(fin)' to 'result = scp.pscpp(fin)' and passed the variable 'result' to file write operation. With this, I am able to write the string value of 'final_string' variable to my respective files. I hope I would now be able to use 'result' variable for my further operations inside 'main.py' file.

Comment: I don't get your question. `result` is there, so just use it?

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to say is the same as to what you just mentioned in your comment. My query is now resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the moving the following block of code from function 'pscpp()' in 'pyscp.py' file to 'main.py' and return the variable final_string in function 'pscpp(self,fin)'.

This writing block inside pscpp() always overwrites all output files after processing every file. That could be the culprit.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    for i in filelist:
        with open(inputdir + i, 'r') as f:
            fin = f.read()
            if i.endswith(".py"):
                scp=Pyscp()    
                result = scp.pscpp(fin)

                file_output = open(os.path.join(outputdir + i +".out"), 'w')
                file_output.write(result)
                file_output.close()

                f.flush()      
            f.close()
```

Comment: Okay. So, if I place the block of code from 'pyscp.py' file to 'main.py' & write the function 'pscpp(self,fin)' and just 'return(final_string)', will my code work?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: okay. My motive of writing them into functions is that I wanted to separate code blocks into functions according to their features. The processing which  I've mentioned before is just a part of my project. I would try out your recommendations, but is there any way where I can keep code blocks separated based on their functionalities?

Comment: You can retain it in the pscpp() function only problem is the for loop to get file name. If you can pass it to the function pscpp(), you retain it there.